# PrimeFaces p:selectOneRadio to be set false on double click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My project requirement is to set `p:selectOneRadio false` as default value.
On single click `p:selectOneRadio` to be set as true and on double click 
`p:selectOneRadio` should be set false.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="#{project.uampaiid}_createUser_access_radiobutton" value="#{dataAccess.accessRadio}"
                  layout="pageDirection"
                  rendered="#{dataAccess.accessRadioSelection}" disabled="#{dataAccess.disableAccessField}"
                  requiredMessage="Please Assign a Access for every role" onchange="reactToChangedRadio(this)" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{dataAccess.roleUserList}" var="accessUser" 
                   itemLabel="#{accessUser.role}" 
                   itemValue="#{accessUser.roleId}.#{dataAccess.accessId}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Please specify where do you make your double click, the best way to get an answer is to add what you have try to do

Comment: On double click on p:selectOneRadio i want to set it false.

Comment: What do you mean by setting a `p:selectOneRadio` to a boolean value? Do you want to deselect a select item on double click?

Comment: This doesn't make sense from a UI design perspective.  If a single user can have many roles I would use a list of checkboxes (one per role), if not I would use a `selectOneMenu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a double click in a p:selectOneRadio you can work with a commandLink

It will look like this

```
 <h:commandLink id="commandLink"  >
   <p:ajax  event="dblclick"  listener="#{managedBean.someMethod()}"  />

   <p:selectOneRadio id="radioButton" value="#{managedBean.example}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="True" itemValue="True" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="False" itemValue="False" />
   </p:selectOneRadio>

 </h:commandLink>
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: and where do you deselect the selectOneRadio?